# transfer several variables to another ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Tell me, please, how should i transfer several variables from one ViewController to another?

For example, i have

**ViewControlle.m**
`- (void) transferVar{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 11;
    }`

and i want to transfer them to another ViewController (SecondViewController.m). What should i do?

Comment: Mark E's answer or you can use a Singleton approach if you want to acceess these variables at all times in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a property on the second view controller for every variable you want to pass (or an array to contain them all), then if you are making the segue on the storyboard use the method
`-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

and inside it make this

`SecondViewController *svc = (SecondViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;`

There you have the view controller you want to pass values so only save it

`svc.yourArray = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:a],[NSNumber numberWithInt:b]];`

Also it is highly recommendable to add a segue identifier to the storyboard segue and check
 `if([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"theIdentifier"])`
to be sure it is the segue that you wanted

Now on the `viewDidLoadMethod` you can use them.

If you are not using the storyboard segue just assign the value after initiating the view.